# I have lost magic mouse2 & keyboard Thanks

Tags: keyboard, mouse

as above I think I have to uninstall and re-install both but theyare undiscoverable as well. . Am I on right track? I'm nogeek also could not find library anywhere. Appreciate help have been at this for hours. Thanks am writing with apple onscreen keyboard and USB mouse.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to edit your question and add the model of Mac you have, the MacOS version it runs and what specific Magic Mouse and keyboard you have (Part/Model numbers usually on the bottom). Note that macOS comes with everything you need to install all Apple branded devices, no "library" needed.

Answer (score 1):

once the mouse and keyboard are close to your computer and turned on, go to the System Preferences and click on either the mouse or keyboard options. Both of these panels have a buttom in bottom right which says Setup Bluetooth Mouse or Keyboard. The panes are shown below.

[image]

And for the keyboard.

[image]

Use these to setup your bluetooth devices.